# Extending asp:SiteMapPath

Tags: asp.net

I'm using

```
<asp:SiteMapPath ID="SiteMapPath" runat="server" skiplinktext="skip breadcrumb"></asp:SiteMapPath>
```

In a SharePoint environment - is there anyway to force it to display the current page?

i.e. [home] > [site name] > [site name] > [page name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows the current page if you defined the page as **siteMapNode** in your site map.